# Word for female dunedain

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

We know that **Edain** are the Men, as a species, and **Dunedain** the High Men from Númenor. We see sometimes **Dunadan** used to refer to a singular male like Aragorn, thus having **Adan** for any singular human male..

Is there a word for a woman of this race?

Comment: They have no women of their own. That's why the poach them from Elves :)

Comment: @DVK Yes, Tar-Ancalimë was quite masculine :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The word is **Dunadaneth**.

This is sourced from the *Athrabeth Finrod ah Andreth*, published in HoME10, *Morgoth's Ring*, where in the course of the conversation Finrod says:

> That is the bitterness, beloved *adaneth*, woman of Men, is it not?

This is consistent with a note in *Quendi and Eldar* (HoME11) where the m. and f. forms of Sindarin *Edhel*, "Elf", are given as *Ellon*, *Elleth*, and *-on*, *-eth* are noted to be gender-specific suffixes.

*Adan* > *Adaneth* therefore didn't undergo the same contraction that we see in *Edhel* > *Elleth*, and with *Dunadan* just being a compound of *Dun-*, "west" and *-adan*, "Man" (i.e gender-neutral "human", not "male": *Dunadan* is therefore a gender-neutral form), and although *Dunadaneth* is not recorded, it is the form it would have taken.  *Dunadanon* would presumably be the gender-specific male form.

I'm not aware of any gender-specific plural forms (there may even be none, although *Dunedanyn* and *Dunedanyth* seem to fit Sindarin plural-formation), nor am I aware of any indication of what the Quenya equivalents would have looked like.

Comment: Interestingly, Q&E also notes that *Dunedain* dates back to the First Age and was used when referring to the Edain in Beleriand (Q was *Nunatani*).  Presumably it was just subsequently taken up by the Numenoreans.  Speculate all you want about the *-eth* in *Athrabeth* and *Andreth*.

Comment: I've removed my answer in light of this far-superior information. :)

Comment: @Martha - I think you should leave it because it contains useful information (specifically the emphasis that *Dunadan/Dunedain* are gender-neutral).

Comment: Your answer contains that information, too, so I don't think my answer was adding anything other than some griping on my part against the type of language nuttiness that objects to "history" because it resembles "his".

Comment: @Martha your answer was interesting, it was just not truly answering the question. I think it is important that you leave it again as it corresponds to the same thinking other people can have in the future when looking at the question.

Comment: @Martha I agree that you should leave your answer.  More information is always a good thing.

Comment: OK, OK, I've undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Given Tolkien's era and his use of language, I'd imagine the word for female Dunedain would be, drumroll please... **Dunedain**.

(Hint: the "men" in "High Men from Númenor" doesn't mean "persons possessing a Y chromosome". It means "members of the human race, rather than, say, elves". Yes, I know people nowadays object to this usage, but in my book, that's just as silly as objecting to the word "history" because it happens to contain the sequence of letters "h-i-s".)

As for the "singular=Dunadan" bit, that's a bit of a misinterpretation: it's still the word for a person of a particular race, not a person of a particular gender. Think *humans* vs. *human*, not *men* vs. *man*. The word for a single male Dunedain is *man*, and the word for a single female Dunedain is *woman*.

Comment: You have not addressed the main point of the question, which is not about Dunedain (plural) but about Dunadan (singular). I can talk about Man as a species, no problem with that, but I will not call my mother a Man.

Comment: "Adan" is just singular of "Edain", both Sindarin and ultimately derived from Quenya "Atan"/"Atani".  The Sindarin plural-formation used here is different to the Quenya; think "mouse"/"mice" versus "house"/"houses", for example.  If referring to females specifically there are suitable words such as "wen" (which is actually species-neutral), but "edain"/"adan" and not gender-specific, so the singular for a non-gender-specific word is also a non-gender-specific word.

Comment: For a "real world" parallel, consider Latin "homo", which was a masculine-gender word, but which meant (at least in classical Latin) "human being".